# Tensorflow fails to run on GPU from time to time

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, gpu

Solved this problem myself. It was because there were too much images in the celeba dataset and my dataloader was so inefficient. The dataloading took too much time and caused the low speed.

But still, this could not explain why the code was running on the cpu while the gpu memory was also taken up. After all I just transfer to pytorch.

---

My environment: windows10, cuda 9.0, cudnn 7.0.5, tensorflow-gpu 1.8.0.

I am working a cyclegan model. At first, it worked fine with my toy dataset, and could run on gpu without main problem(though the first 10 iterations took extremely long time, which means it might be running on cpu).

I later tried celeba dataset, only changed the folder name to load the data(I loaded data to the memory all at once, then use my own next_batch function and feed_dict to train the model). Then the problem arose: the GPU memory was still taken according to GPU-Z, but the GPU-load is low(less than 10%), and the training speed is very slow(took more than 10 times than normal), which means the code was running on CPU.

Would anyone please give me some advise? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the batch size that you were trying? If it's too low (something like 2-8) for a small model, the memory consumed will not be much. It all depends on your batch size, the number of parameters in your model, etc. It also depends on the model architecture and how much of the model has components that can be run in parallel. Maybe try increasing your batch size and re-running it?

Comment: The batch size is 4. In fact the image size(96*96) and batch size(4) were not changed and it used to be ok with a smaller dataset. I only changed the folder name that contained dataset, and the problem arose.

Comment: if changing the folder name is the *only* modification that was made, then it may be a coincidence. Did you try setting it back to the original configuration and re-running it?